# How to get a value from nested array?

Tags: php, arrays, nested

Trying to fetch the first URL field from an array of them that comes from a JSON I have decoded but I get this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\blabla

```
 foreach($data-> images as $data2) {
 print_r(images[0]['url']);
 }
```

I hope its enough of my code to work out what I am doing wrong?

Added: I would like the first "url" and it was getting the last one hence why I am changing the code and trying to debug it here.

Comment: most likely a typo `(images[0` missing `$`

Comment: @Ghost Where are you getting `$images` from??

Comment: I was thinking that too. Cheers for the help attempt sincerely of course but there is no $images in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your `foreach` you use the variable name you specified in the definition:

So something like...

```
foreach($data->images as $data2) {
   print_r($data2[0]['url']);
}
```

Although, depending on the structure of the array, I'd imagine that you don't need the number, so it might be:

```
foreach($data->images as $data2) {
   print_r($data2['url']);
}
```

If you wanted to loop through the values by a number, you'd use a `for` loop

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($data->images); $i++)
{
    print_r($data->images[$i]);
}
```

Comment: That done it. You are a genius! Thanks. =)